# There's any alternative to MasterDetailPage when using Xamarin.Forms with ReactiveUI ViewModel-First?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I think that the title/question says almost it all, but a just making a long version:

I'm started a project with Reative UI (first time) and Xamarin.Forms and I'm really enjoying it.

Today I spent almost all my afternoon trying to find a way to create/use the MasterDetailPage from Xamarin.Forms to build that regular drawer menu. The problem is: I'm using (or trying too) the Router and ViewModel-First Navigation.

So, there's any way to accomplish this kind of menu with Reactive UI?

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to solve this problem?

Comment: I end up creating a custom solution. I can upload that somewhere if you need it.

Comment: Yeah, a git page or something would be awesome